# dev.meta "ask question" link appears broken

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

http://dev.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask is returning an error.  Chrome is helpfully filtering out the error code and suggesting I do a google search to find the information I need.

Comment: What is that `dev.meta`?

Comment: @Earlz, it is a playground for selected few. Hint http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/03/stack-overflow-api-private-beta-starts/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you caught dev in the middle of a build.

Remember you're on our dev tier so you may get deployment interruptions way more frequently than the production tier.